# Sorting the project space list in Bitbucket

Tags: bitbucket

Is there a way to sort the list of project spaces in Bitbucket? We started using Bitbucket for just a small section of the company now the entire company uses it and we have about 40 project spaces and Bitbucket and the order seems random. The original projects added years back are on the bottom (when we started using Stash 3.x) and all the newer ones (since upgrading to 4.x) are ordered alphabetically on top.

I'm sure I can poke around in the database to solve this but I'm looking for a UI- or API-based solution.

Answer (score 0):

Projects in Bitbucket Server should sort in alphanumeric order. If you're not seeing that, you're experiencing a bug.

I work for Atlassian and I found and reported [just such a bug](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BSERV-9807) when Bitbucket 5.0 was released. If perchance you're running one of the affected versions, you can resolve it by upgrading to a more recent version.

If you're running an older version than the ones listed in the above bug report, it's still possible you're running into a similar or the same bug - we list "affected versions" based on customer reports, so it's possible the bug existed on an older version but was never reported. On that bug report I provided a python script to easily reproduce the issue on a test instance, so if you can tell me the version of Bitbucket your company is running I can test it to see if it's reproducible.